# How to pre-define the text box for e-mail and/or phone number

Tags: c#, email, textbox, phone-number

I am wondering if I have two text boxes for **Phone** and **Mail** how can I allow only digits (let's say US standard 1-234-567-8910) and only a real e-mail(aaaaaaa**@**bbb**.**cc) to my text boxes correspondingly in c#?

Comment: what you using  a winform or webform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Masked TextBox` For this and put Validation on `TextBox` Validating Event
Try this Link  [Phone Number Validation](http://www.smartwebby.com/DHTML/us_phone_no_validation.asp)  it may help you

Comment: Is there a way to do it with simple TextBox? Otherwise I have to do a lot of changes...

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `jQuery` plugin named `mask`
[click here](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

Comment: I have no idea of jQuery, and my application has nothing to do in web environment :(

Comment: may this help [Win Forms text box masks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259850/win-forms-text-box-masks)

Answer (score 0):

In WinForms you can use the `ErrorProvider` in conjunction with the `Validating` event to handle the validation of user input. The Validating event provides the hook to perform the validation and ErrorProvider gives a nice consistent approach to providing the user with feedback on any error conditions. You can use regular-expression validation inside this event to check the pattern of email or phone number.  More detail is [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For WebForm:
You can use HTML 5 validation, which is very easy use and understand.
Here is [link](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/) 
It is client side validation so it is very useful to you.
In example at above provided link, use validation attributes in server control as it is.

For WinForm :
You can use maskedTextBox [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/maskedtextbox)

Comment: He is using WinForm not Webform.

Comment: @ Dharmesh i thought so, and it is not mentioned in the question. So your answer is not down voted ;)