# Regex to mask Textbox text?

Tags: c#, regex, wpf

I want to prevent users for typing wrong text in Textbox.

Allowed pattern to type in should be only XXXX-XXXX. First 4 characters digits only, preceding with "-" character and ending with 4 letters (case irrelevant).

Example:
1234-abCd (correct)
12A4-abcd (wrong, a letter in first 4 places)
12345abcd (wrong, "-" missing)
etc.

I was thinking about a regex match to match Textbox text in PreviewTextInput, something like this:

```
private void _txt_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    var txt = (TextBox)sender;
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[^0-9]{4}\-[^a-z]{4}");
    e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(txt.Text + e.Text);
}
```

If Text doesn't match a regex expression, then typing in Textbox should be prevented.
By that I mean even while typing - "123A" should not even occur, "A" shouldn't be allowed to type at position 4.

Sorry for my bad regex knowledge in advance, I'm still learning It.

Can this be done with Regex, and how ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259850/win-forms-text-box-masks

Comment: Well, while typing you only have 1, 2, 3 ... characters, which will not match the 9 you're expecting. You can't achieve that so easily with Regex and e.Handled

Comment: Note that `^[^0-9]{4}-[^a-z]{4}` are 2 negated character classes that match any char except a digit 0-9 for the first one and any char except a char a-z for the second one. I think you meant `^[0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z]{4}`

Comment: As @ThomasWeller correctly pointed out, you have a problem in applying the regex *as* the input is keyed into the textbox. One possible solution to this issue, create a different regex expression for each length from 1 to 9 characters. And in your handle event, check the length of the input and choose the regex for the data entered. Ultimately you need to ensure the final length and 'final' regex are applied to the final input value.

Comment: @Thomas Weller, my concerns exactly. However I don't want to use MaskedTextBox which WPF provides. I want to build and style my own TextBox control. And Regex seemed to be a way...

Comment: @quaabaam, I was thinking something simmilar, but I asked here anyway, maybe someone knows an answer. Could be useful for others too.

Comment: Or (referencing @quaabaam's suggestion of 9 regexes), create a perfect match string. As each character is entered, concatenate what's in the text-box with the last (9-currentLength) characters and match with the one regex.  Make perfect be `"1234-ABcd"`.  Then, after three characters are entered (say `"12b"`), concatenate that with `perfect.Substring(3)` (i.e., `"4-ABcd"`) yielding `"12b4-ABcd"`, which results in a failure. If they had entered `"987"`, then the result would be `"9874-ABcd"`, which would be a success

Comment: @Flydog57, that sounds better, but I still don't have a regex for complete string. Can you post an example ?

Comment: This would seem to fit your spec: `@"^[0-9]{4}\-[a-zA-z]{4}$"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm always wondering why everyone thinks Regex can magically solve stuff, especially input verifications ;)

First, split your problem into actual patterns which Regex can match:

- 1-4 Digits
- 4 Digits with an `-` and 0-4 letters at the end

Then create the Regex for those

- `^\d{1,4}$`
- `^\d{4}-[A-z]{0,4}$`

And combine them

- `^\d{1,4}$|^\d{4}-[A-z]{0,4}$`

This Regex should match as long as the input is valid (according to your specs). If it is not sufficent, repeat and improve.

Here are some test-cases
[image]

Please Note: This will only prevent the user from typing character you don't want. It will NOT prevent them from copying random strings into the Textbox.

Additional Advice: You shouldn't assume the input i correct because you prevent the user from entering things you don't want. Always check the input later in your Business logic (eg. when adding a new entry/item/etc.).

Comment: thanks for answer. I needed to handle some Keys too, but your example works. Thanks again :)